Excel model issue
I have a model in which I can set a particular Category to either 1 or 2 (cell C2).
I have a series of numbers aligned to either Category 1 or Category 2 (using, for example, IF(B6=1,H6,H7) ) and I want to be able to find the difference between values in each category. I use a self-referring IF statement to keep the category 2 value "locked" on the spreadsheet (for example, the formula in cell D6 is IF(B6=2,C6,D6)). I then want to be to be able to switch back to category 1 (by adjusting the value in cell C2), and have the spreadsheet show the difference between the two (the formula in cell E6 is simply D6-C6).
However, the difference always shows as zero. I check the Evaluate Formula function and it somehow steps through to be 30-5=0. If I hard-code the D6 value, the E6 subtraction works correctly. I really want to avoid this, as it will make downstream maintenance of the model difficult.
I think it's something to do with the self-referring IF, but I don't understand why, or how to fix it.
Image 1 is the spreadsheet showing the formulas I've used; image 2 is the same spreadsheet showing the results.
This is Excel as part of M365 for Enterprise, version 2404. VBA is out, due to organisational security restrictions. Any help gratefully received. Thankyou.
EDIT: added actual model details below.
The image below shows the formulae in my model:
.
This image is the baseline position:

And this image is my toggled set of figures, with cell AA33 now set to "offshore":

I'm expecting column AA to contain the difference between column Z and column X. Hope this clarifies.

Can you show us your expected output?

As the formula in column E shows, I'm expecting the output to be 25 in column E (30-5). It is currently zero.

Why don't you use XLOOKUP : =XLOOKUP(IF(B6=1,2,1),$G$6:$G$7,$H$6:$H$7)

I've created a very much simplified model for the purposes of asking this question. In reality, the values in columns C and D will vary hugely based on calculations elsewhere in the model - they won't be static numbers that I could put in a reference table.

And how do you then identify "the other category". I think you should show a more realistic data set and your expected output - otherwise it is difficult to help you.

I have edited the post to contain details from my actual model.

Looking at your first image, instead of IF(B6=2,C6,D6) try IF(B6=2,$H$7,$H$6). Notice that when you use D6 in formula in cell D6 you are creating Circular reference

In reality, the values in columns C and D will vary hugely based on calculations elsewhere in the model - they won't be static numbers that I could put in a reference table. The second example clarifies. The circular reference is intentional, and the only way I could figure  out to keep a calculated value on the spreadsheet with a toggle controlling multiple options.

Why not list both option costs (separate columns, no toggling) and calculate the difference between those two? Circular references are asking for trouble.

But in the end you're looking for the cheapest option, so it seems, and the total savings compared to the other. Why then calculate all cells separately, when you could create one SUM or SUMPRODUCT for the whole per cat value
